# Include js and css in ZF2 using AJAX or not

Tags: zend-framework2

I have some views in ZF2 that must include js and css files.
I can do so in view:

```
$this->headscript()->appendScript(...
```

But, when I get view result using ajax I need to get from server array with view html, css includes and js includes. Like this:

```
array(
    'html' => '<div id="timepicker-wrap"></div>',
    'js_include' => array('/js/timepicker.js'),
    'js_eval' => '$("#timepicker-wrap").timepicker()',
    'css_include' => array('/css/timepicker.css'),
);
```

After I give this data to client-side my js library will include html, js and css.

The problem is to get all js and css files and code from headscript in server-side.

Am I right that I have to extend HeadScript, HeadStyle and InlineScript classes and add functions that returns all js and css? Or I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all js and css from headScript, headStyle and InlineScript using getContainer() method

```
$this->headScript()->getContainer()->getValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the layout when using Ajax quite easily, one example:

SomeController.php

```
public function myAction()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->layout('application/layout/ajax-layout');
    }

    return new ViewModel();
}
```

application/layout/ajax-layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->content ?>
```

When you try and access somecontroller/my/ using an Ajax request, the base layout, which includes your head/js/etc will not be rendered.

it will be rendered when you view with a normal request though.

There's a couple of other ways of doing this, but this is probably the simplest :)